# PostgreSQL: pass path from psql to create table name dynamically

Tags: postgresql, psql

Suppose I have two paths, `/data/dev` and
`/data/prod`. When developing, I want to use the `dev` directory, and in prod I want to use the `prod` directory.

I need to upload data at some interval (`upload_to_tables.sql`):

```sql
file := :basedir || 'file.csv';
COPY my_table FROM :file WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

I tried running this, `$ environment=dev; psql -d my_database -v basedir="'/data/$environment'" -f upload_to_tables.sql`

I get this error:

```
2019-07-15 09:24:52.302 CDT [90820] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "file" at character 1
```

How can I path the directory from which these data need to be loaded in a dynamic fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close. The following should work.

```
$ environment=dev && psql -d my_database -v basedir="/data/$environment/" -f upload_to_tables.sql
```

```
\set file :basedir 'file.csv'
COPY my_table FROM :'file' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

Usually you shouldn't bother with quotes when setting variables. You can access the variable's content as a string with `:'var'` or as an identifier with `:"var"`.

To concatenate variables and store it as a new variable you can simply list multiple values after the variable name in `\set var value`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script which displays file contents, something like

```
$cat ts.sh  

#!/bin/bash
basedir=/data/dev
file=${basedir}"/file.csv"
cat ${file}
```

Now, the `\copy` or `COPY` can use the `PROGRAM` option

```
\copy t from program 'ts.sh' with delimiter ',' CSV
```